# What happens to election votes when a sock puppet is deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, deleted-users, sock-puppets

I discovered a larger sock puppet network today. I flagged the user and they were nicely cleaned up (thank you!), so everything's fine here.

However, I noticed that even the few socks I could find had more than 300 reputation (more than enough for voting in the elections), and more than one account had a fresh [Consituent badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent), meaning that the user voted multiple times from their accounts in the current moderator elections. This made me wonder about the current system:

1. What happens to election votes when a user is deleted?
2. What happens to election votes when a sock account is nuked?

This also got me thinking, and it occurred to me that in many countries [felony disenfranchisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_disenfranchisement) is a thing, i.e. certain kinds of criminal offenders are banned from voting. Considering how it's *highly* unlikely that someone *accidentally* votes multiple times from multiple accounts and forgets about this in the few days available for voting, we can safely assume that users who use their sock accounts for voting are very aware that this is wrong. I'd also note that I've seen users "joke" in public chat about using their sock accounts to vote in the elections. Finally, these users are exactly the kind who should *not* decide who runs as moderator on the site.

This brings me to an additional request for community input:

3. Would we want to entirely election-ban users who abuse the election system by using multiple accounts to vote?

Comment: 1> I expect the votes are just deleted. Par for the course for user deletions, yes? 2> Same thing, but let's not equate voting on some website to actual criminal vote fraud. 3> Ban, sure, but make sure it's not the wrong person. I could see some sneaky jerk stacking votes for a candidate they want to see banned.

Comment: @BoogaRoo I'm not talking about excluding _candidates_; I'm only talking about excluding _voters_ who try to vote multiple times. Removing socks means that they are left with at least 1 set of votes from their main accounts. The question is whether we should rid them of those too.

Comment: The fact that the stakes are lower means that there's no reason to pull the punch as far as consequences. A wrongful felony conviction in the real world can destroy multiple persons' lives, so we need to be careful and commensurate. Here, you cheat to get some unicorn points...you're so petty, why would we want you playing in the sandbox anymore?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, I think we're talking about a rounding error here. There were only four users involved in the group you flagged earlier, and I suspect this is more of a voting ring than a series of puppets. I deleted two of the accounts because they had little in the way of useful contributions, and it was easier to just get rid of them than ask SE for vote invalidation. Unless I'm remembering incorrectly, I think one or both of those didn't have enough reputation to vote in the election.

So we're talking about a couple of votes here. In the last election, 30277 people voted in the final stage.

Most people who operate sock puppets do the bare minimum to get them to upvote, so they tend to be below 100 reputation most times. The people who are doing this are mostly using their puppets to evade question bans. Again, I'd say this has little effect in the election, even if the votes were to remain.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! When I started writing the question I hadn't seen that two users remained, so at that point I thought that the master and a sock both voted. Of course if it's partly a voting ring, they're free to cast their votes each. My question would still apply in general, but then again your point of socks usually having little rep answers that well. I admit that I was primed by 1. old anecdotal evidence of elaborate high-rep socks in one of my tags, 2. the user in chat hinting at voting with socks and 3. the current events. Thanks again for the awesome work:)

Comment: Also, if I recall correctly both users lost enough rep that they no longer have 150 rep to be eligible for voting. But _this_ edge case is definitely not worth asking about.

Comment: Voting fraud! It's voting fraud! Millions and millions of sock puppets including deleted ones conspired to rig the... I'll shut up now.

Comment: @Mysticial that's such fake news... the biggliest fake news... ;-)